# Is .relatedTo().total() returning all source elements if none are found?

Tags: entries, categories, relations

I'm using categories and relating them to entries.

If using `.relatedTo().total()` I'm seeing the total number of ALL entries if none of the entries are related to a particular category.

If using `.relatedTo().find()|length` then zero is returned as expected.

I'm trying to output a link list of all categories with their total related entries IF they have any entries.

Here is the code I'm using (with a testing snippet to show how `|length` is working.

```
{% set cats = craft.categories.group('topic') %}
{% for cat in cats %}
  {% set total = typeEntries.relatedTo({targetElement:cat}).total() %}
  {% if total %}
    <li><a href="{{ urlPrefix ~ '/topic:' ~ cat.slug }}">{{ cat.title }} ({{ total }})</a></li>
    testing length: {{ typeEntries.relatedTo({targetElement:cat}).find()|length }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Strange. I'm getting the same result for both `.total()` and `|length` (with or without the `find()`).

Comment: I know, it's bizarre. Must be some kind of strange edge case... or maybe it's because this is my first Craft site :-). For now I'm just using `.find()|length` so it displays as expected.